# Which tactics are there to keep a branch on top of master without tons of merge-commits?

Tags: git

On one hand rebasing is an awesome way of keeping a branch on top of master, but force-pushes are painful if more than 1 person is working on it and gets impractical when there are even more branches being derived from that branch.

On the other hand constant merges of master into the branch clutter the history and make a final interactive rebase just before merging it back to master even harder if not possible at all.

I wonder where do I find a list of common ways of keeping a collaborative branch actual?

Comment: If you have to constantly merge master into your branch, you're not really doing separate work. Do you *need* to merge from master into your branch, other than to do testing and so on towards the end? If so, can't you create a temporary branch for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "lists of things" are not good answers here on Stack Overflow. We invariably end up with lists of answers with lists of things, and all the answers have a tendency to overlap slightly. If you're instead asking for a link to such a list, that is also off-topic here.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen
1. Keeping a branch on top of master is crucial to stick to continuous integratin of all features being developed.
2. I am happy to retitle it to "How to ...?" question, will it suffice?

Comment: I still don't think you will find a conclusive answer, just a discussion. But, keeping a branch on top of master, when you rebase, should get rid of the merges. The problem is that you're rebasing branches in development by multiple people, that's not recommended I think.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, okay, thanks for the suggestion, will remove the question now. Can you suggest where do I go with it, is it SO chat or something?

Comment: Could be, but I'm not sure there is a good git-room, but it's been a while since I looked. Otherwise, anyone in the development rooms would probably be the audience for such a discussion so you might just pick the room for the programming language you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Rebase is the way to go if you don't want merges.

If it creates pains, maybe you want to reassess your workflow, for example:

- not have multiple people working on the same branch,
- if a branch is meant to have subbranches, rebase it only once it is ready to be merged in master,
- so on.

But as Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen says, it's more ideas and directions than a definite answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your main problem is the way you coordinate your work:

> On one hand rebasing is an awesome way of keeping a branch on top of master, but **force-pushes** are painful if more than 1 person is working on it and gets impractical when there are even more branches being derived from that branch.

Emphasis mine.

A force push is something that you should *never have in normal workflow*. Independent of whether your merge or rebase. **A force push means that you rewrite *published* history**, and that is something you want to avoid.

So, if you want to rebase, **don't push before you rebase**. Keep your commits private, and you can do with them whatever you like. Once your commits look good for publication, push them. Once your commits are pushed (=public), they should not be rewritten anymore. Use merge commits instead.

Also, my experience is, that many people are way too worried about keeping "a linear history". The truth is, history is not linear, and it's generally better to record the truth than a linear lie, imho. Git has been built especially for working with non-linear history, there is absolutely no technical reason to keep linear history. Linear history may be a tad easier to parse for humans, but if the price for the linear history is that some commits become untestable due to rebase-errors (can easily happen if you don't retest each and every rewritten commit after a lengthy `git rebase`), then you have just thrown away one of the best tools offered by `git`: `git bisect`. That command simply works best if you avoid lying about history.

Don't get me wrong: `git rebase` has its uses, and `git push -f` exists for a good reason as well. All I'm saying is: **These tools have unavoidable negative consequences, and if you don't put in any effort to mitigate them, you shouldn't be using them in the first place**. They are not built to be used in a mindless way. If you need to use these tools, you also need to put in the effort: 1) Retest all rewritten commits. 2) Communicate with your team members about any necessary forced push. Fail to do so, and you get the problems you describe.

Comment: Nice thoughts, exactly what I was thinking myself. But do you really tolerate tons of merge-commits in a branch? If a branch lives for, say, 10 days, one better keep it up to date with master once a day to avoid a snowball of conflicts, so it is 10 merge-commits. Isn't it a hell to navigate?

Comment: @DanielVartanov I guess, that depends a bit on the nature of the changes within the branch. If people are working on sufficiently disjunct features, I don't think a daily merge is really that necessary. One option is to fetch changes, check whether they still merge without conflict, and then to forget about the merge commit. Or, the other way round: If a merge produces too many conflicts, abort and retry the merge with some intermediate commit. Your merging happens locally, so you are free to experiment as much as you like.

Comment: @DanielVartanov Also, if you merge, you don't need to re-merge old commits. If you rebase a branch several times, the first commits will be rewritten over, and over again. Not so with merging: In this case, you only need to incorporate the *new* stuff into the current state. A last note: I've found setting `merge.conflictstyle` to `diff3` much more important for fixing merge commits than keeping a branch up-to-date daily. With `diff3` conflict markers, you can see exactly what upstream has done to the conflicted hunk, and what you have done, and can thus find a sane resolution easily.